# PHP preg_replace for anything on a line that starts with //

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to remove single line comments from a js file. Of course, all of the lines will look something like:

```
// This is a comment in a js file
```

What is the regex to remove everything on a line that begins with `//`?

I'm already using this to remove multi line comments:

```
/* This is a
   multi-line comment */

$js = preg_replace('!/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*/!', '', $js_contents);
```

Thanks!

Comment: How will you handle `"// this is a comment - lol, nope, it's a string"`?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: What do you mean? Any line that starts with two forward slashes are commented out.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol probably by making sure the line *starts* with `//`

Comment: I thought the idea was to remove single line comments. Single-line comments don't have to be all there is on a line, they can easily by at the end of a line too.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: Yes, that's true. Maybe I should rephrase to say anything on a line that follows two forward slashes

Comment: @JohnRobinson Got you covered ;) See my answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your suggestions, but there wasn't one that took care of removing the comments correctly. I found this solution, that seems to be working quite nicely- removes single and multi-line comments, whether they appear at the beginning or end of a line:

```
$expr = '/(?:(?:\/\*(?:[^*]|(?:\*+[^*\/]))*\*+\/)|(?:(?<!\:|\\\)\/\/.*))/';
$js = preg_replace($expr, '', $contents);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this more robust solution:

```
$regex = <<<'REGEX'
((?:/\*[\s\S]*?\*/|"(?:[^\\"]|\\.)+"|'(?:[^\\']|\\.)+')(*SKIP)(?!)|//.*)
REGEX;
$js = preg_replace($regex,"",$js_contents);
```

Explanation:

- Match

  - all multiline `/* ... */`-style comments*
  - OR all double-quoted, single-line strings (multiline strings aren't valid JS)
  - OR all single-quoted, single-line strings
  - SKIP AND FAIL the above
- Match `//` to the end of the line

  - Remove it

Regex verbs FTW

*You can remove this part if you've already stripped multiline comments

EDIT: You may wish to use a similar build for your multiline comments regex:

```
$regex = <<<'REGEX'
((?:"(?:[^\\"]|\\.)+"|'(?:[^\\']|\\.)+')(*SKIP)(?!)|/\*[\s\S]*?\*/)
REGEX;
$js_without_multiline_comments = preg_replace($regex,"",$js_contents);
```

This will allow you to have `/*` in your JS strings without it causing problems.

A couple of notes:

- The use of NOWDOC string syntax allows the regex to be written without spending ages worrying about "is this backslash going to be read by PHP or the regex?". It'll be given to the regex every time this way.
- The use of `[\s\S]` instead of just `.` allows for multiline matches. The `s` modifier is unsuitable here because we want to match single-line strings.

Comment: I'm having trouble using this... I can't paste this right into a PHP file it throws syntax errors.

Comment: @JohnRobinson Make sure that the `REGEX;` is at the *very start* of the line it is on - there must not even be a single space before it, otherwise it won't be treated as the terminator. If that doesn't help, please tell me what the error message says.

Comment: Something is not being processed right. I've posted a pic highlighting the issues: http://i61.tinypic.com/14mfls7.png NOTE: Sorry about the size... it must have resized when I uploaded it.

Comment: Good use of backtracking control here, +1

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
$js= preg_replace('#^\s*//.+$#m', "", $source);
```

or this another:

```
(\/\*[\w\'\s\r\n\*]*\*\/)|(\/\/[\w\s\']*)|(\<![\-\-\s\w\>\/]*\>)
```

Hope it works :)

Edit: I made the test with the second expression and it works to single comments :)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to remove comments that do not appear in the beginning of the line. Maybe I should have been more clear with my question. Basically, remove anything on a line that appears AFTER two forward slashes.

Answer (score 0):

Already made a test with one javascript file containing this code and test this php script and remove all the comments, give a try:

```
<?php
$js = file_get_contents('script.js', true);

try {
$newjs= preg_replace("/(?:\/\*(?:[\s\S]*?)\*\/)|(?:([\s;])+\/\/(?:.*)$)/m", ' ', $js);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e;
}

echo $js . '<br/><br/>';
echo $newjs;
?>
```

**script.js**

```
function getPNGBase64forHtml(container) {
    var imageString;

    html2canvas(document.body, {
        useCORS: true,
        logging : true,
        proxy :"html2canvasproxy.php",
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function() {
                img.onload = null;
                document.body.appendChild(img);
            };

            img.onerror = function() {
                img.onerror = null;
                if(window.console.log) {
                    window.console.log("Not loaded image from canvas.toDataURL");
                } else {
                    alert("Not loaded image from canvas.toDataURL");
                }
            };

            imageString = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        }
    });

    return imageString;
}

// function getPNGBase64forHtml($container) {
//     var h2canvas = html2canvas($container);
//     var queue = h2canvas.parse();
//     var canvas = h2canvas.render(queue);

//     return canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
// }
```